# I'm trying to playmusic using service but it's not working

Tags: android, android-service, android-mediaplayer, android-service-binding

from here i started the service

```
         Intent intent=new Intent(getActivity(),MyService.class);
        s=sn;
        u=ur;
    intent.putExtra("uri",u);
            ServiceConnection serviceConnection=new ServiceConnection() {
                @Override
                public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
    MyService.LocalBinder binder = (MyService.LocalBinder) service;
    myService=binder.getService();

            }

            @Override
            public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
                myService=null;
            }
        };
        getActivity().startService(intent);
```

this is my service class

```
    public class MyService extends android.app.Service {
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer=new MediaPlayer();

    String str;
    private final IBinder binder = new LocalBinder();
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        // str=intent.getStringExtra("uri");
        Toast.makeText(this, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        this.str=intent.getStringExtra("uri");
        try {
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(str);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if(!isplaying()){
            mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    startmusic();
                }
            });

        }
         return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }
    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        MyService getService() {
            // Return this instance of LocalService so clients can call public methods.
            return MyService.this;
        }
    }
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {

        return binder;
    }
    public void startmusic(){
   mediaPlayer.start();

    }
    public void stopmusic(){
        mediaPlayer.stop();
    }
    public boolean isplaying(){
        return  mediaPlayer.isPlaying();

    }
}
```

i'm getting this error

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service com.example.firebasemp.MyService@da4ba03 with Intent { cmp=com.example.firebasemp/.MyService (has extras) }: java.lang.IllegalStateException"

on this line
"mediaPlayer.setDataSource(str);"

Comment: have you tried reading docs: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer#managestate ?

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski i've read it but i'm not sure where i'm making the mistake

Comment: the player is state sensitive, and you cannot i.e. pause the player that is not actually playing nor start the one that is not idle. The error you facing indicates that the state of player is not allowing what you want it to do. If unsure, just peek the state. Also check `isPlaying()` etc. so you must update your code to check that instead of doing certain actions unconditionally

Comment: btw: `str` in `setDataSource()` line is what exactly? remote resource? local file?

Comment: str is the uri from firebase

Comment: can you post the one that causes you problem?

Comment: please answer your own question then and briefly explain what was the problem so future readers can benefit from it.

Answer (score 0):

i added `mediaPlayer.prepare();` after `mediaPlayer.setDataSource(intent.getStringExtra("uri"));`
the problem is when we play audio before starting we need to prepare it first